# Analytics tracking wrong url - including base domain after /

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I was checking Analytics stats for my Magento store and found a few weird URLs with dozens of hits. The URLs where like this:

/domain.com

/checkout/cart/domain.com

Now I don't understand why Analytics is tracking those URLs as I cannot replicate this from my Magento store. I checked all the links manually and also checked my server logs, but can't find a clue about what is happening.

I'm  using Magento Community 1.6 on a Nginx server, with Redis caching set. I also use Cloudflare.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check... app\design\frontend\base\default\template\googleanalytics\ga.phtml to see if it's doing anything out of the ordinary/has been customized and if not turn on google analytics and see which block is rendering the backwards logic.

Comment: Hi Vladimir.. I checked the file you mentioned and there is nothing strange in it (no custom code). I just see the plain GA code there. I just don't know how to check the block with is rendering the backwards logic that you suggested. Can you help me?

Comment: system->configuration->change website scope to website you're debugging->developer->turn template/block hints to on and view page source. Debug what code is/and if is generating the google analytics code on each page load and what appears to be off in it.